# Matlab Simulink Random number generator block

Tags: matlab, random, simulink

I am using a random number generator block with a controlled voltage source to generate noise in my circuit. There is a 15V voltage source seperate from controlled voltage source. What would be a 'realistic' value for variance in the random number generator block?

---

Initially i have every value set on default setting:

---

Mean: 0
Variance: 0.1
Seed: 0
Sample time: 0.1

---

So i want the controlled voltage source to output 'realistic' changes in voltage (noise).

Comment: so why don't you use the "Band-Limited White Noise" source block?

Comment: @thewaywewalk should i leave the value at [0.1] for the noise power?

Comment: well that depends what kind of noise you want to implement, that's the first you need to know. Than you can calculate the noise power. Formulas you could find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_(physics))

Comment: If you have an resistor for example you need to add thermal noise and use the according formula.

Comment: Thanks guys, ended up deleting the block anyway as the variance was too high and it represented too much noise.